# PHP (codeigniter) back end is automatically chopping POST data from AJAX call

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, post

I'm submitting data through an ajax post, the post data will be called `list` in this example. The backend is using PHP codeigniter.

I make the ajax POST call, `list` is an array with 190 objects in it. If I `console.log` it, it correctly shows 190.

`$.ajax({
    url: submitUrl,
    type: 'post',
    data: { list },
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});`

I post the data. I pull the data out of the post object..

`$data = $this->input->post();`

then I send a response back to the front end..

`print count($data['list']);`

I receive it in the `success`, and the response shows the number `40`.

I know for a fact the data is coming in correctly(if I just return the array, it shows a chopped version of the array - but I just made it a number for simplicity). It returns the *first* 40 items in the array if I do that.

Why is the back end chopping trimming my array?

Things I've tried:

- adjusting `php.ini`:

`upload_max_filesize = 100M`

`post_max_size = 100M`

- adjust `htaccess`:

`LimitRequestBody`

`php_value upload_max_filesize`

`php_value post_max_size`

does anyone else have any other ideas?

---

*Update:*

Never solved the core of the issue. Ended up using `JSON.stringify(list)` on the front end and `json_decode($data['list'])` on the back end to get around the issue.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `data: list` or something similar (without enclosing in an object with `{}`, as it already is an array)? And in your backend just `print count($data);`?

Comment: Is your XSS filter enabled? Did you try `$data = $this->input->post(NULL, FALSE);`?

Comment: @AlejandroIván it's just destructured js, so essentially saying the key is `list` with the value of the list variable

Comment: @BA_Webimax tried doing that, not successful